# writing a string into large number of files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

I have created 10 files using touch command on  linux terminal in a directory having only these created files.

```
 $ touch a1.c a2.c a3.c a4.c a5.c a6.c a7.c a8.c a9.c a10.c
```

I want to write a string "stackOverflow"(say) into all these files at a time .
How to do that?Is there any command or some other way ?

Platform -ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Write a string == only this string? Append?

Comment: This looks more like a programming language job than a command line job for me... you could create parallel threads to do this kind of job. But the real question is: Why do you do this? Sync of something? Should use other ways from this point of view...

Comment: You could have created these 10 files directly with the content: `for i in $(seq 10); do echo stackOverflow >a$i.c; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command prompt (Bash)

```
for f in *.c; do echo "stackOverflow" >> $f; done
```

Comment: what if i want to put some content of other files in all these files? .e.g. i have standard headers in a file and i want to write it in all these file

Answer (score 1):

Once your data is in an array it is easy to loop over, see the example.

Just save this in an empty file writeStringToFiles.sh and right click it then under the permissions tab click Allow executing file as a program. You can double click it or run it from the terminal by "cd" to the directory its in then just type "./writeStringToFiles.sh". You can put any commands you want in a bash script like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
files=(a1.c a2.c a3.c a4.c a5.c a6.c a7.c a8.c a9.c a10.c)
thingToWrite='stackOverflow'

for i in "${files[@]}"
do :
    touch $i
    echo -e $thingToWrite >> $i
done

exit
```

Comment: It worked for me, I just edited it and removed the semicolins see if it works for you now, just copy paste into gedit or nano

Comment: I am not sure whats going on, try this, open up gedit paste "#!/bin/sh echo hello" no quotations and save it as test.sh now right click it then under the permissions tab click Allow executing file as a program, then run it from the terminal, this does work. Other wise see yourself http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_br4MEDygw

Answer (score 1):

If you files are not empty(at least 1 byte):

```
$ sed -i '1i\
stackOverflow' a{1..10}.c
```

will insert `stackOverflow` at the beginning of every file.